# How to get Mail.app to show email addresses?

Tags: macos, mail.app

In 10.7's Mail.app, it shows all recipients as a blue bubble with a name in it.  In order to see the email address, I have to click on the right side of the bubble, to get a pop-up menu.

This is a big pain, especially when I have more than one recipient.  I can only see one address at a time.

Is there a way to get Mail.app to show me actual email addresses, either in addition to or instead of the "name" it's using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Mail.app, then go to *Mail* in the top menu > *Preferences* > *Viewing* > Uncheck *"Use Smart Addresses"*.

This should display the full name of the contact plus the email address.